# Как использовать библиотеки с++ в андроиде

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk

Есть код на с++, как использовать его в андроиде с помощью NDK?
Просто по синтаксису непонятно,нет нормального описания
Это в андроид студии все подчеркивает.
P.S.: все `#include` я сделал

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Answer (score 0):

[схема по запуску натива, нужно увязать CMake и Gradle, тут все прям на пальцах](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code)

Comment: сам NDK работает, я же написал, что по синтаксису непонятно. Я знаю с++, но тут все не так. complex на вход принимает два параметра в конструктор, тут только один, та и в <> указываешь тип, который будет(класс template), а оно все подчеркивает, если какие-то примитивные вещи(строку вывести или что-то подсчитать(+/*-)), то все нормально, а так...